Interior stud wall height acceptable gap
I'm framing in non-load bearing walls in my basement.  The total height of the basement from concrete floor to bottom of above joists varies between 97 7/16" to 97 5/8" but is primarily 97 1/2" throughout the basement.  With 2x4 standard 8' stud lengths of 92 5/8", 2 top plates (3"), and one bottom plate (1 1/2") my walls will end up being 97 1/8".
For a non-load bearing wall, is the 97 1/2" - 97 1/8" gap of 3/8" a concern, expected, or ideal?  Should I shim every wall at the top plate? Should I skip 92 5/8" studs and get 96" and trim each one to length instead?
This is a mock up with a 92 5/8" stud (and 3 total plates):

This is the overall area where I'm adding a new wall with a 92 5/8" stud:


Couple notes: you should use a pressure treated 2x4 for the bottom plate in contact with concrete. If you attached that plate, and built/raised a complete wall, your length problems would go away. If you were stick framing (ie, piece by piece), then you’d have a length problem that you could just shim.

@AloysiusDefenestrate - I will be using PT for the bottom plate (and sill seal).  The 1 1/2" PT bottom plate is already factored into my overall height.  I'm not sure why my length problem would go away?  Are you saying that building on the floor and raising it results in a different overall height then stick framing in place?  How so?

@AloysiusDefenestrate a gasket is also acceptable.

The simple fact is that almost all interior basement walls have such a gap. It's very putzy work to custom fit each stud to the variations in floor slab height, so most carpenters find the short spot and fit to that, assuming reasonable variation.

The advantage of assembling the wall on the floor and standing it up in place, is first the gap will allow the wall to be stood in place easily as opposed to driving in a tight fitting wall, not easy. Second, if you stick build it getting each stud accurately on the lines at the top with a gap to deal with is a wiggly situation. The stud will not stay still vertically while attaching the top to the plate. If you assembled the wall on the floor and stood it up, holding it from toppling by a temporary or loose set nail/screw or 2 set the bottom permanently, then finished off the top securely.

Sorry — missed that you had 3 plates in the plan to begin with. Short studs and shims will be fine. This is just opinion, but I’d put a double plate on the floor. And again opinion, but I don’t love gaskets. Plenty of folks love them; I feel like mini floods can still soak the lumber.

Since the wall is non-load bearing, just use long enough screws or nails to anchor the top. Shimming is not required, but it sometimes makes you feel that it is more secure.
On a personal note, I like it when the height is a little over 8 feet so I can jack up the bottom panel of drywall and keep it off the floor.

Are you basically saying, its non-load bearing so this is "close enough"?  I haven't ordered my studs, so should I just order 96" and spend the extra 10 total mins to cut each one to the proper length?  Why not?

@dpollitt,  That your choice .  If it were me, I would just use precut studs and not worry. Here in my location, (FL.)  homes are framed with a small gap as you have quite often.   The shimming is more for a mental feeling of well being, but not required.
